# SQL SELECT Query with group and distinct

Tags: sql, database

I have table with 4 columns (`id, bm, name, act`).

I want to retrieve records grouped by `bm` and count how many records have of every group where `act = no` and where `act = yes` at once...

So if I have records:

```
(Id, bm, name, act)
1, 5, Nik, yes
2, 6, Mike, yes
3, 5, Tom, no
4, 5, Alex, no
```

Result I need is:

```
(bm, totalYes, totalNo)
5, 1, 2
6, 1, 0
```

I guess that everything is possible to retrieve from SQL but I don't know how :(

Comment: so where you are facing issue..and put snippet what you have done

Comment: @LazaBre Try following. `Select SUM(CASE WHEN act = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NoCount, SUM(CASE WHEN act = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) YesCount from tbl group by gm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to achieve this result:

```
select 
  bm, 
  sum(case when act = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as "Count of yes",
  sum(case when act = 'no'  then 1 else 0 end) as "Count of no"
from t
group by bm;
```

With some databases, like MySQL, you can reduce the aggregation to `sum(act = 'yes')`, but the ANSI SQL standard requires the full case expression.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/66bd9/2)

Comment: omg, thank you so much, this was so fast ;) i was trying with distict and some other stuff, now i see where i was wrong... ok one more q :(  what if i want to make one more column with (yes -(minus) no)  btw sorry if i bored you..

Comment: @LazaBre If you want `yes minus no` then subtract the second case expression from the first. See this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/66bd9/5

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you ;) if you ever come to Serbia you have beer from me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN act = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NoCount, 
SUM(CASE WHEN act = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) YesCount 
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY gm
```

Answer (score 0):

Since aggregate functions typically skip nulls, you can create two columns `TotalYes` and `TotalNo`, with a value `NULL` for cases you don't want to include in your count.

Here's what I mean:

```
SELECT 
     bm, 
     COUNT( CASE act WHEN 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) TotalYes,
     COUNT( CASE act WHEN 'no' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) TotalNo
FROM tbl
GROUP BY bm
```